# Isn't the jQuery text() function cross browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the text that contains the element inside a td. Even not knowing what's inside this td using the jQuery `mytd.text()` returns the text successfully in IE8.

However I noticed that this function `text()` **may be not cross browser** since it returns me diferent values in Chrome and FF than in IE8. In both Chrome and FF the string result is much longer than in IE8. It's preceded and appended with empty values `" "`

As of I have a variable `mytd` that has the td object how could I retrieve the text that contains in a cross browser manner?

```
   // Does not work
   var text = mytd.text()
```

thank you.

Comment: can you make a fiddle so we can test it out?

Comment: By "empty values", do you mean that the string has whitespace at the start and end of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** cross-browser, but different browsers handle white space in text node differently, and jQuery doesn't abstract that.

It does provide the `$.trim` method to help you out though.

To strip the white space when you retrieve the text, just do this:

```
var text = mytd.text().trim();
```

... this assumes `mytd` refers to an existing jQuery variable of course. You could do this:

```
var text = $('.mytd').text().trim();
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I tested that in Safari which implements the native String.trim() method; to have it work in all browsers you should do this:

```
var text = $.trim( mytd.text() );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery.trim(str)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) that removes empty spaces from the start/end of a string.

Eventually, you don't even need jQuery to trim a string, since all strings share a `trim` method on `String.prototype`.